# How to cancel / close a behavior subject in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have a component that is subscribed to a behavior subject in the `ngOnInit` life cycle. This component html uses `ngIf` to see if data is there before rendering the table.

When I navigate away from the page, I am wanting to make sure that the next time I come back, the table isn't visible until that data is then fetched again. The only way I have been able to do this so far is by calling next on the subject and sending an empty string, which feels wrong..

**Component:**

```
mapMetaData: any;

ngOnInit() {

    // Subscribe to our map data
    this._mapsService.uiMapMetaData
    .subscribe(
        results => {
            if (results) {
                this.mapMetaData = results;
            }
        }
    );

}

/**
 * Implement onDestroy life cycle
 * 
 * @memberof ViewMapComponent
 */
ngOnDestroy() {
    this._mapsService.updateMapMetaData('');
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<span *ngIf="mapMetaData">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3 class="text-primary">{{ mapMetaData.TargetName }} <small>{{ mapMetaData.TargetDesc }}</small>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" role="button" (click)="backToMaps()">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Back to Maps
            </button>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <app-map-versions [targetID]="targetID"></app-map-versions>
    <app-map-exceptions [targetID]="targetID"></app-map-exceptions>
    <app-map-rules></app-map-rules>
</span>
```

The issue is, without sending the empty `next` to the behavior subject, `mapMetaData` still contains what it received from the previous `next` call, resulting in the table showing when I come back to it, containing old data, and then very quickly changing when new data is received.

Is there a better way to handle this or am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Have you tried to use only `Subject` instead of `BehaviorSubject` ? `BehaviorSubject` stores last value but, Subject doesn't store the last value.

Comment: You could use a resolver in the router to make sure the new data is loaded before the navigation ends.

Comment: @asmmahmud Is it my subscription that is the issue though? Technically, the variable i define in the component is what gets the value and if thats not cleared out, its still going to cause the `ngIf` to think there is data and show the element, correct?

Comment: For normal circumstances, what you're doing is okay, but, for your special case, you can give it a try by using `Subject`.

Comment: onDestroy `this._mapsService.unsubscribe()`, but you may also an is loaded in your subscribe to go true, and on destroy false

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `asObservable()` to get a `Observable` from you `BehaviorSubject` and store the subscription object and `ngOnDestroy` you can `unsubscribe` :

In you mapServie class:

```
 private mapSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(mapdata()); /* you get the idea */
 public mapObservable = this.mapSubject .asObservable();
```

Then you can do the following:

```
mapMetaData: any;
subscription: Subscription;
ngOnInit() {

    this.subscription = this._mapsService.uiMapMetaData
    .subscribe(
        results => {
            if (results) {
                this.mapMetaData = results;
            }
        }
    );

}
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Newbie question: why the extra lines of code ? Since BehaviorSubject is also an Observable you could subscribe and unsubscribe directly from 'mapSubject' and skip the '.asObservable()' part ?

Comment: How do you handle a "global" unsub like you would using `takeUntil()`, like if you have 50 subscriptions.