# How to destroy a BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, typescript, behaviorsubject

You are using BehaviorSubject to exchange and execute functions between components.

My problem is that the BehaviorSubject functions are always being executed, when in fact I just want them to be executed depending on my actions (clicks).

Did I do something wrong? How can I solve this, can someone help me?

**What I tried**

TComponent.ts

```
 subscription: Subscription;

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}

  this.subscription = this.taskprofileService.dataTask.pipe(filter(y => !!y)).subscribe(y => {
      this.pauseTimer(y);
    });

    this.subscription = this.taskprofileService.timerInfo.pipe(filter(x => !!x)).subscribe(x => {
      this.sendInfo(x);
    });
```

Comment: Do this answer your question - [Answer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45971076/11719787)

Comment: @SameerKhan Thank you for trying to help me. I've seen this post but I couldn't apply it, I had a lot of doubts and it didn't work on what I tried :(

Comment: what error are you getting when you implement the suggested answer ? @MatSigh

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama 
My first doubt was where to apply this. I must apply this to the TaskProfile service, right? Can you give me tips?

Comment: You need to apply this on `.ts` file where you have subscribed. @MatSigh

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama so... in my taskComponent.ts right?

Comment: Exactly. @MatSigh

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama 
already updated the post with what I tried, but it didn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206969/discussion-between-pushprajsinh-chudasama-and-mat-sigh).

Comment: I don't know that I understand you correctly but maybe you should use Subject instead of BehaviourSubject. BehaviourSubject works that you always get value on the start subscription so the message that the stop function was executed always has to run a minimum once.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `unsubscribe()` in ngOndestroy like following . 
User the Subject instead of `SubjectBehaviour` 
**.ts** file
    subscription: Subscription;

```
  this.subscription = this.taskprofileService.dataTask.pipe(filter(y => !!y)).subscribe(y => {
      this.pauseTimer(y);
    });

    this.subscription = this.taskprofileService.timerInfo.pipe(filter(x => !!x)).subscribe(x => {
      this.sendInfo(x);
    });

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

**Service File**

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
  public dataTask = new Subject<any>();

  public timerInfo = new Subject<any>();
  StopTimerInfo(taskInfo){
      this.dataTask.next(taskInfo);
  }

  SendTimerInfo(taskInfo){
      this.timerInfo.next(taskInfo);
  }
```

Try out the following method using Subject. 

For more information , [refer this document](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/02/07/angular-7-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think the subject should be advised for what I want. So I no longer need to use the constructor?

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helps you . Happy to help you . @MatSigh

Comment: Not working yet, this.taskService.currentTaskInfo arrives as undefined

Comment: Will provide you a stackblitz tonight . @MatSigh

Comment: The problem is that when using Subject the SendTimerInfo (event) function {
    this.currentTaskInfo.next (event);
  } is not sending the data :(

Comment: Ohk got your problem . @MatSigh

Comment: As I switched to subject, the way of calling or sending must be changed :(

Comment: You need to first initialize or call the component where you are wishing to get the response of `SendTimerInfo()` .

Comment: When I execute the Stop function in the taskprofile ... Whenever I enter the Tasks page I always receive the message that the stop function was executed, that is, the BehaviorSubject is always being executed :(